# How to open text files with Pycharm in Windows

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

maybe this question is very stupid but at the moment I am unable to find the solution for it myself.

I want to open a text file which is on my desktop with my Pycharm Community Editor (running with Python). So in the book it says you can open it with:

```
fin = open('words.txt')
```

Obviously this is not working and I tried it with something like:

```
fin = open('C:\\User\\Julian\\Desktop\\words.txt')
```

But all I get there is this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "", line 1, in 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\User\Julian\Desktop\words.txt'

And I tried any other combination of forward and backward slashes. So, what am I missing? I am realy lost with this on windows :/

Thx in advance :)

Comment: Isn't it `C:\Users\...` (note the plural)?

Comment: Yeah you are right. But I also tried it with the plural. The problem was something else but I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself. Was some stupid extension of the filename.
Found it with the help of this os command:

```
print(os.listdir("C:\\Users\\Julian\\Desktop\\"))
```

it listed all the files and so I found out that there was some sort of "invisible" file extension. Then it worked.

Answer (score -1):

If all you want to do is create a .txt file, use File Explorer or your OS' equivalent to go to that directory your project is located in, and manually create a text file there.